# How to make the region where function > 0.5 more visible with Plot3D?

Tags: plotting, functions

I want to make it more clear to see the region where `1/(x/y - 2)>0.5`. Can anyone help make it better to see? 
 Or please suggest if you have a better idea to show this (with or without Plot3D).

```
Plot3D[{1/(x/y - 2), 0.5}, {x, 4, 5.5}, {y, 0.4, 1.2}, 
 PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Comment: Plot3D[Max[1/(x/y-2),0.5],{x,4,5.5},{y,0.4,1.2},PlotLabels->{x,y,z}]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f[x_, y_] = 1/(x/y - 2);
part1 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 4, 5.5}, {y, 0.4, 1.2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z > .5], 
   PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 8, 
   PlotStyle -> Cyan];
part2 = Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, 4, 5.5}, {y, 0.4, 1.2}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, z < .5], 
   PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}, Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> LightYellow];
Show[part1, part2]
```

[image]

Or

```
Plot3D[{1/(x/y - 2)}, {x, 4, 5.5}, {y, 0.4, 1.2}, 
 MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, z], Mesh -> {{.5}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Opacity[.5], Red}, PlotLabels -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found a nice solution via searching so I'll post it as well.

```
ContourPlot[1/(x/y - 2), {x, 4, 5.5}, {y, 0.4, 1.2}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, 1/(x/y - 2) < 0.5], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Red]
```

[image]